# ASP.NET Core - Pages with `[Authorize]` attribute cannot be found when app is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize

I have an ASP.NET Core application running locally where I can access pages using `[Authorize]` attribute. However, I can no longer access pages that use the `[Authorize]` attribute when I publish my app to my server. I get the following error:

> This page can’t be found.

Other pages without the `[Authorize]` attribute are working fine.

I found where my application is getting an error on my published version. I'm guessing my SignInManager isn't working correctly when I published it. How could I configure it?

Here's the code of my service.

```
public class IdentityAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private UserManager<IdentityApplicationUser> userManager;
    private SignInManager<IdentityApplicationUser> signInManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public IdentityAuthenticationService
    (
        UserManager<IdentityApplicationUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<IdentityApplicationUser> signInManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
    )
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        //This line is where the error comes from
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (!result.Succeeded) {
            throw new InvalidLoginException();
        }
    }
    [...]
```

Comment: What kind of Authentication\authorization are you using? Windows Authentication?

Comment: I use an AspNetCore.Identity Authentication. A collegue made it for me but he isn't working with me anymore..

Comment: Did you look at the logs to see the actual error you are getting? Authorize does not give 404's unless the account controller's views are not setup properly. Edit the question and add startup.cs and a testcontroller. Looking at that might help someone trying to answer the question. As is your question is too broad.

Comment: I just added my startup.cs and my HomeController like you sujested. Looking at my console from the developer Tools, I get a 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @DaveFortin-Labrie Did you figure out the solution? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with Authorize attribute, but more likely routing.

If you try to access a controller or action with Authorize attribute, but are not authorized, you should see only a blank page. You can verify this by removing Authorize attribute from the problematic page, and I bet you will still get the same error.

Comment: I just removed the Authorize from one of the controller that wasn't working on my publish version and now I can access it without any problem...

Comment: In that case i suspect there is some additional authorization logic somewhere that is trying to redirect, or to do something else that messes up routing.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've just edited my question to show where my problem comes from. I don't know if that can help to figure out what the problem could be...